# Setting up one goal in Google Analytics to be tracked by several Adwords Accounts

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads

Is there a way to have one goal in Google Analytics and have it be associated with several accounts within Google Adwords.

One goal is working fine for one account in Adwords, but the other accounts are having a hard time finding any goals to pull in.

All the setup required by http://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034306?hl=en have been setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question (sort of).
I would used AdWords conversion code. Paste each code from each account onto your conversion page one after the other (if it is page).
Not only will that work - but you won't have to import the goal to AdWords, and you'll see the conversion data far quicker in AdWords.